# Python Pyramid Error on pserve

Tags: python, linux, python-2.7, web, pyramid

After running

```
pserve development.ini
```

I get the following error message.  I did not change any of the setup files.  After the error I did change the port to 6543 from 8080.  One file had 6543 the other had 8080.  Reran the setup and received the same error.  Any help, I am extremely new to pyramid. I used the following guide: http://docs.pylonsproject.org/projects/pyramid/en/1.3-branch/narr/project.html#project-narr

```
Starting server in PID 30147.
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/bin/pserve", line 9, in <module>
    load_entry_point('pyramid==1.8.3', 'console_scripts', 'pserve')()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pyramid/scripts/pserve.py", line 40, in main
    return command.run()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pyramid/scripts/pserve.py", line 235, in run
    server(app)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/paste/deploy/loadwsgi.py", line 189, in server_wrapper
    **context.local_conf)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/paste/deploy/util.py", line 55, in fix_call
    val = callable(*args, **kw)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/waitress/__init__.py", line 21, in serve_paste
    serve(app, **kw)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/waitress/__init__.py", line 11, in serve
    server = _server(app, **kw)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/waitress/server.py", line 39, in create_server
    adj = Adjustments(**kw)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/waitress/adjustments.py", line 180, in __init__
    raise ValueError('Unknown adjustment %r' % k)
ValueError: Unknown adjustment 'listen'
```

Comment: What WSGI server are you using? What tutorial did you use to create the project? Why are you using docs that are several years old?

Comment: What does your development.ini look like?